# Google Colab not taking complete data from cifar10

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

print("[INFO] loading CIFAR-10 data")
((trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)) = cifar10.load_data()
trainX = trainX.astype("float") / 255.0
testX = testX.astype("float") / 255.0

print("trainX: {}, testX ={}".format(trainX.shape,testX.shape))

lb=LabelBinarizer()
# convert the labels from integers to vectors
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)

labelNames = ["airplane", "automobile", "bird", "cat", "deer",
"dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]

print("[INFO] compiling model")
opt=SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0.01/40, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model= MiniVGGNet.build(width=32,height=32,depth=3, classes=10)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])

#train the network

print("[INFO] training network..")
H=model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
        batch_size=64, epochs=40, verbose=1)
```

The output is:

```
[INFO] loading CIFAR-10 data
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
170500096/170498071 [==============================] - 4s 0us/step
trainX: (50000, 32, 32, 3), testX =(10000, 32, 32, 3)
[INFO] compiling model
[INFO] training network..
Epoch 1/40
782/782 [==============================] - 10s 12ms/step - loss: 1.6249 - accuracy: 0.4555 - val_loss: 1.3396 - val_accuracy: 0.5357
Epoch 2/40
782/782 [==============================] - 9s 12ms/step - loss: 1.1462
```

When I download the data from the website above, I get the correct cifar data but when I run my model, I can see it only takes 782 images.
I have worked on other models as well but same result.
 This only happens in google colab and not in my local pc. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a Colab-specific issue

Comment: Yes, I think so, any suggestion on where to ask, because I know others are facing the issue too

Comment: Can you provide rest of the code you used? The code you provide is insufficient because it doesn't contain any training code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the training and testing sets are working perfectly fine. Train set has 50000 images and the test set has 10000. So, there is no problem in the code that you posted. Consider adding rest of the code that you used to train the model. You can check the shape of your sets by executing.

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = cifar10.load_data()
train_X = train_X.astype("float") / 255.0
test_X = test_X.astype("float") / 255.0

print(f"train_X: {train_X.shape}, test_X = {test_X.shape}")
```

[image: perfectly fine shape of data]

Update:

Tested this in MyBinder, my local Juyter Notebook and Colab and got to this conclusion:

MyBinder and local Notebook didn't separate CIFAR training set into mini-batches or just showed total number individual data-points in training set. So, they show showed that `50000` steps were necessary at each epoch.

On contrary, Google Colab has mini-batched the CIFAR dataset into `64 mini-batches` and has trained the model. So the total `steps` at each epoch is `5000/64` which is equal to `782`.

[image: Mini Batch]

Hope this cleared your confusion. It was just that Colab displayed total mini-batches, whereas Jupyter Notebook showed total invidual number of entities in the set.

PS: You might want to add missing bracket at the end of line 34 in the code that you shared [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_QBGtzN8y6uNpb5MNYHDoykWDvRTAgZ/view).

Comment: I have added my other part of code, also I got the same shape for train_X and test_X

Comment: What are you referring to by "MiniVGGNet"? That is not imported. I think you have renamed the import, and the original import code is missing. Please tell me from which library have you imported it. Then I might be able to help.

Comment: Please refer to the updates and consider adding this as answer if it answered your question.

Comment: That was very silly of me, using GPU for the 1st time and the epochs going so fast, I thought the data was not complete, anyhow thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question on colab, would be grateful for your help: [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156893/displaying-figure-from-another-class-in-google-colab-using-matplotlib)

Comment: @Hrushi You're welcome! I will look into it and see if I can help.

Comment: Here is the minivggnet  [class] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZU7LRVljymm1Fu6jC5OPGX_STYUq9rrA) in case you need it. Sorry for deleting it earlier.