# Displaying figure from another class in Google Colab using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, google-colaboratory

In google-colab:

I have a python code which uses a class from another file. The class has a method which has the following code:

```
def callbacks():
        plt.style.use("ggplot")
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(N, self.H["loss"], label="train_loss")
        #code continues
        plt.legend()

        #save the fig
        plt.savefig(self.figPath)
        plt.close()
```

This method( part of "callbacks") is invoked every time in each epoch when I run the code of the main file.:

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
        batch_size=64, epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1)
```

But I couldn't get the figure in google colab but it is being saved at the correct location(as expected)
What I did but failed are:

1. using plt.show() before plt.savefig(..)
2. runnning `%matplotlib inline`   before the start of the code

What should be done to dislpay the plot as the epochs are run?
The reason I want them to run as the epochs are displayed is because it is taking some time to update the figure on google drive

Answer (score 1):

Once `plt.close()` is called, the figure is closed. The only way to display the figure after calling the above code is to remove `plt.close()` from the code you are calling.

As a last resort, if there's no way to edit this code, you could monkey-patch the close function before calling the code in question; for example:

```
plt.close = lambda: None
```

but be aware that this overriding core functionality like this is a very bad idea and will likely have unintended side-effects elsewhere.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work for me. I have tried to run the code before and after running the `%matplotlib inline command` but couldn't get the graph to be displayed. However it was being successfully saved and updated in drive